# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable - json - python

Tags: python, json, pandas, apache-kafka

I need some help.

I converted a dataframe to a json using df.to_json
I am now trying to send this json message to kafka, but I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Another problem: For some reason, my json value has been changed. For example. In my dataframe I have column called phone_number witch have a phone number, but in json just show "00000-0000" as value.
Also I have a column dataframe called create_date but in json do not show real value, just a negative number.

```
{
    "id": "3702353",
    "create_date": -610588800000,
    "update_date": 1427155200000,
    "description_address": "Karangahape Road",
    "phone_number": "00000-0000"
}
```

Does anyone knows what is wrong here?
I have tried `value=str(row)`  but still getting the same error

```
data = df.to_json(orient='records', force_ascii=False)

bootstrap_servers = 'my-host-server'
topic = 'my-topic'

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
                        value_serializer=lambda x:json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8') )

for row in data:
    producer.send(topic, value=row)
    producer.flush()
```

Comment: the error happens when you call `df.to_json` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it makes sense to start of with what goes into the `.to_json()` method. Could you print out the `dtypes` of the DataFrame? And maybe the first few lines of df as a whole? My first question would be whether you have the dtypes assigned correctly. Maybe the dates are stored as dates in the DataFrame e.g..

Please also note that the documentation shows that the way dates are printed out, is depended on the orientation, in your case records.

Lastly I want to note that the value of a Kafka event can be seen as plain text. Naturally this text can be a structured JSON, but I am not sure whether it would convert this manually to string or not. To transform a JSON to text, you should use the JSON library:

```
import json

example = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "New York"
}

stringed_json = json.dumps(example)
type(stringed_json)
```

But I am not sure whether this is something that you need to do when are using this already in your serializer..

Comment: Hi @Pieter Geelen, Thank for reply

I have print all dtypes of my dataframe. I can see my columns date as datetime and phone_number as object. 
`INFO - DataTypes: 
id                 object
name               object
birthday           datetime64[ns]
gender             object
create_date        datetime64[ns]
update_date       datetime64[ns]
description_address   object
number_address        int64
phone_number          object
cell_phone_number     object
dtype: object

<class 'str'>`

I still do not know what is going on here.
I am going to post my whole fd in other comments

Comment: Hi @Pieter Geelen
Sorry, I don't know much how to use this website, but here are my whole df
`{
    "id": "3702353",
    "name": "Maria Rene Gutierrez de Santistevan",
    "birthday": -610588800000,
    "gender": "Male",
    "create_date": 1427155200000,
    "update_date": 1427155200000,   
    "description_address": "Karangahape Road, Auckland",
    "number_address": 22,
    "phone_number": "00000-0000",
    "cell_phone_number": "00000-0000"
}`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your dataframe into list of dict

```
 my_data = df.to_dict('records')
```

and then iterate your list and send to kafka

```
for record in my_data:
    producer.send(topic, record)
    producer.flush()
```